# my goal was to create clusters using random data and I am getting this warning and no clusters

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

````
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from itertools import cycle
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
%matplotlib inline
np.random.seed(0)
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=5000, centers=[[4,4], [-2, -1], [2, -3]], cluster_std=0.9)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], marker='.')
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
from sklearn import metrics
af = AffinityPropagation(preference=-50).fit(X)
cluster_centers_indices = af.cluster_centers_indices_
labels = af.labels_
n_clusters_ = len(cluster_centers_indices)
print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
colors = cycle('bgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmyk')
for k, col in zip(range(n_clusters_), colors):
   class_members = labels == k
   cluster_center = X[cluster_centers_indices[k]]
   plt.plot(X[class_members, 0], X[class_members, 1], col + '.')
   plt.plot(cluster_center[0], cluster_center[1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col,
           markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)
   for x in X[class_members]:
       plt.plot([cluster_center[0], x[0]], [cluster_center[1], x[1]], col)
plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()```
````

Estimated number of clusters: 0
/Users/alexkaram/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_affinity_propagation.py:250: ConvergenceWarning: Affinity propagation did not converge, this model will not have any cluster centers.
warnings.warn(

I was expecting 3 clusters and visualizations

Comment: I find it converges if you set `AffinityPropagation(preference=-50, damping=0.9)`. Ends up finding 29 clusters, though.

Comment: Tune hyperparameters of `AffinityPropagation()` in `af = AffinityPropagation().fit(X)`